# Python win32 com : how to handle 'out' parameter?

Tags: python, com

I need to access a third-party COM server with following interface definition (idl):

```
interface IDisplay : IDispatch
{
  HRESULT getFramebuffer (
    [in] ULONG aScreenId,
    [out] IFramebuffer * * aFramebuffer,
    [out] LONG * aXOrigin,
    [out] LONG * aYOrigin );
};
```

As you can see, it returns 3 values via [out] parameter modificators. How to handle this via python win32 COM api? For example, i create an object and get IDisplay from it:

```
object = win32com.client.Dispatch( "VirtualBox.VirtualBox" )
display = object.display
```

How to call display.getFrameBuffer() so it will work? I have tried different ways, but it's always 'type mismatch' on second argument ([out] for IFrameBuffer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since those are out parameters, can't you simply do the following?

```
Framebuffer, XOrigin, YOrigin = display.getFrameBuffer(ScreenId)
```

There is some good references in [Python Programming on Win32 Chapter 12 Advanced Python and COM](http://www.icodeguru.com/WebServer/Python-Programming-on-Win32/ch12.htm)

And they indicate that the syntax should be like above. They also mention using 
MakePy for COM objects:

There are a number of good reasons to use MakePy: (copied from the book)

- The Python interface to automation objects is faster for objects supported by a MakePy module.
- Any constants defined by the type library are made available to the Python program. We discuss COM constants in more detail later in the chapter.
- There is much better support for advanced parameter types, specifically, parameters declared by COM as BYREF can be used only with MakePy-supported objects. We discuss passing parameters later in the chapter.

Comment: I have tried, it raises 'invalid number of parameters'. I'm not sure how to use MakePy if COM server is third-party. It's installed on the system as a binary and registers COM server. Is it possible to change it's API?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `makepy` module, invoking it as follows:

```
>>> import win32com.client.makepy as makepy
>>> makepy.main()
```

A window will open with a list of type libraries. Scroll to "Virtual Box Type Library" and select it, then click "OK". A Python module will be created in a location which is printed out (typically `%TEMP%\gen_py\2.x\`).

The generated class will automatically be used by `win32com.client.Dispatch`, but if you need it explicitly you can access it via functions in the `win32com.client.gencache` module.